# JSP include variable passing

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, include, server-side-includes

Let's say I have a file called `a.jsp` which includes another file:

```
<%
String a = "Test";
%>
...
<%@include file="b.jsp"%>
...
```

The file `b.jsp` accesses the variable from the file it gets included from:

```
...
<%= a %>
...
```

If `a.jsp` gets called everything works fine and the string gets printed even though it was declared in another file.

Nevertheless `b.jsp` can't be called by itself and the syntax highlighting marks the reference to `a` as an error because the variable `a` is not present in in this file.

So my question is: Is there some way to 'import' another JSP file or to allow a file only to be included by a specific other file?

Comment: If you want b.jsp to be included by only a.jsp, then create a scripting variable in a.jsp that can be used like a password.  In b.jsp, use a conditional that will check for that password. If it does find the password, then it will proceed to do its scripting. Don't use any templete text, use out.print lines in the conditional script.  This way when an unauthorized file trys to include b.jsp, it won't get any output.

Comment: @rickz That would work for the security aspect. But there is still the problem that file b doesn't know it's included from file a and therefor has to access to its variablels and content.

Comment: File b will have access to flie a's  variables.  You are using the include directive.  File b is merged with file a during the translation phase. Did you try using my idea?

Comment: @rickz I did and I know that access to variables works. Still the syntax highlighting marks these variables as error because they cannot be resolved in the scope of file b. So I have to compile a program with errors that actually aren't errors at all. Is there any way to avoid that problem? (That's what I ment with importing the other file)

Comment: I guess that you are talking about errors in your IDE.   Could you compile your program without file b ?  Once your web app is on the server,  you could add file b at that time.

Comment: @rickz How is that gonna fix the errors in the IDE? To be honest I still think the problem isn't IDE based since passing on a private key as you said is just some kind of workaround that disallowes the access to the page itself but doesn't fix the entire problem. I mean it works, so I'm greateful for that, but it doesn't fix the problem at it's root.